# Issue with Makefile recipe for inputting object files

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile, that I edited so that object files should go to a separate directory.
I edited the makefile and it is now doing what I wanted to, but during linker stage it is not working as expected because I am doing something wrong.
I have a `sources` file and `makefile` as shown below:

**Sources File**

```
TARGET = demo

SRC_DIR = modbus/ascii/ \
    modbus/functions/ \
    modbus/port/ \
    modbus/rtu/ \
    modbus/ \
    ./

INCLUDE_DIR =   modbus/include/ \
    modbus/port/ \
    modbus/rtu \
    modbus/ascii \
    ./

SOURCE =    modbus/ascii/mbascii.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfunccoils.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfuncdiag.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfuncdisc.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfuncholding.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfuncinput.c \
    modbus/functions/mbfuncother.c \
    modbus/functions/mbutils.c \
    modbus/port/port.c \
    modbus/port/portevent.c \
    modbus/port/portserial.c \
    modbus/port/porttimer.c \
    modbus/rtu/mbcrc.c \
    modbus/rtu/mbrtu.c \
    modbus/mb.c \
    demo.c \
    startup_LPC17xx.c \
    system_LPC17xx.c
```

**Makefile**

```
include ./sources
ARCH = arm-none-eabi
BUILD_DIR := build/objs
# Tool definitions
CC      = $(ARCH)-gcc
LD      = $(ARCH)-gcc
AR      = $(ARCH)-ar
AS      = $(ARCH)-as
CP      = $(ARCH)-objcopy
OD      = $(ARCH)-objdump
SIZE    = $(ARCH)-size
RM      = rm
Q       = # @./quiet "$@"

# Flags
CFLAGS   = -W -Wall -O0 --std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb 
CFLAGS  += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
ASFLAGS  =
LDFLAGS  = -nostartfiles -specs=nosys.specs 
CPFLAGS  =
ODFLAGS  = -x --syms
PRFLAGS ?=

# Source files
LINKER_SCRIPT = LPC17xx.ld

OBJS   = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
BUILD_OBJS := $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(SOURCE:.c=.o))
OBJ_DIR := $(dir $(BUILD_OBJS))

INC_PARAMS = $(foreach d, $(INCLUDE_DIR), -I$d)

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)

.PHONY: all size clean nuke

all: $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET).hex

isp: $(TARGET).bin
#   @./quiet $< cp $^ $(MBED_VOLUME)/

size: $(TARGET).elf
    @$(SIZE) $<

%.hex: %.elf
    $Q $(CP) $(CPFLAGS) -O ihex $< $*.hex

%.bin: %.elf
    $Q $(CP) $(CPFLAGS) -O binary $< $*.bin

$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    @touch $(@:.elf=.map)
    $Q $(LD) -Xlinker -Map $(@:.elf=.map) $(LDFLAGS) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(BUILD_DIR)/$^ -o $@ 
    $Q $(OD) $(ODFLAGS) $@ > $(@:.elf=.dump)
    @$(SIZE) $@

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $(BUILD_OBJS))
    $Q $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PARAMS) -c $< -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@

.PHONY: clean
clean:  CRUFT=$(shell find . -name '*.o' -o -name '*.d')
clean:  ; rm -f $(CRUFT); rm -f *.elf *.hex *.bin *.dump *.map; rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
nuke: clean
    -rm -f *.hex *.bin *.dump *.map
```

The issue is in line:

```
$Q $(LD) -Xlinker -Map $(@:.elf=.map) $(LDFLAGS) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(BUILD_DIR)/$^ -o $@
```

For which the output is:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Xlinker -Map demo.map -nostartfiles -specs=nosys.specs  -T LPC17xx.ld build/objs/modbus/ascii/mbascii.o modbus/functions/mbfunccoils.o modbus/functions/mbfuncdiag.o modbus/functions/mbfuncdisc.o modbus/functions/mbfuncholding.o modbus/functions/mbfuncinput.o modbus/functions/mbfuncother.o modbus/functions/mbutils.o modbus/port/port.o modbus/port/portevent.o modbus/port/portserial.o modbus/port/porttimer.o modbus/rtu/mbcrc.o modbus/rtu/mbrtu.o modbus/mb.o demo.o startup_LPC17xx.o system_LPC17xx.o -o demo.elf
```

The output command picks only the first object file from correct directory under `build/objs`.
Rest object file path doesn't have `build/objs/`.

Please anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Replacing `$(BUILD_DIR)/$^` with `$(BUILD_OBJS)` resolved the issue. But is it the right thing to do? It seems that I am under utilising the GNU make features!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating [Mad Scientist's second rule of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/), and inviting more problems than you know.

Look at these rules ([simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(BUILD_DIR)/$^ -o $@ 

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@
```

Suppose the build directory is `build/` and the object file is `build/foo.o`. The target of the second rule is `foo.o`, but what it actually builds is `build/foo.o`. Likewise, the first rule claims `foo.o` as a prerequisite, but it doesn't actually use `foo.o`, it uses `build/foo.o` These two errors cancel each other out, in a sense; Make succeeds in building the main target. But as you have found, it has trouble if there is more than one object file, because if the prerequisite list is `foo.o bar.o`, then

```
`$(BUILD_DIR)/$^`
```

expands to

```
build/foo.o bar.o
```

Also, Make will run the second rule even if `build/foo.o` exists and is up to date, and will fail to run it if `foo.o` exists. The target of a non-PHONY rule should be the name of the file it builds, and a non-PHONY prerequisite should be the name of a file whose existence is relevant:

```
$(TARGET).elf: $(BUILD_OBJS)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the issue. The link for Makefile rule is really helpful. I thought that providing my complete Makefile and source file would help others understand the issue, but I will make sure to provide only necessary information from next time onward if I have to ask question.